# Subsetting rows from Matlab for which specific column has value greater than zero

Tags: matlab, subset

I want to subset rows from matrix for which the value in third column is greater than zero. For example, I have a matrix :

```
test =

     1     2     3
     4     5     0
     4     4     1
     4     4     0
```

Now I want to subset it so that I have

```
subset  =

     1     2     3
     4     4     1
```

Any quick suggestion on how I can do this in matlab?

Comment: Quick suggestion for now and future - Look into [logical operations](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply make a logical array that is true for every row you want to keep, and pass it as the index to the rows:

```
subset = test(test(:,3)>0, :)
```