# How can I subset an array with a logical condition?

Tags: matlab

I have this array. And I want to subset the whole array for `all values of column 3 that are greater than 0.09` (for example).

```
>> var1(1:10,:)

ans =

   1.0e+04 *

    5.2590    0.0000    0.0905
    5.1743    0.0000    0.0846
    5.0896    0.0000    0.0889
    5.0345    0.0000    0.0905
    5.0896    0.0000    0.0913
    4.8947    0.0000    0.0896
    4.9498    0.0000    0.0889
    5.0049    0.0000    0.0924
    4.9498    0.0000    0.0975
    4.8100    0.0000    0.0900
```

### Expected outcome

```
5.2590    0.0000    0.0905
5.0345    0.0000    0.0905
5.0896    0.0000    0.0913
5.0049    0.0000    0.0924
4.9498    0.0000    0.0975
4.8100    0.0000    0.0900
```

How can I do this? Since this is not a table, I can't access them by column name. So this page, wasn't very helpful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-array-rows.html

Comment: It's `var1(var1(:, 3) > 0.09, :)` for real greater than (your statement) or `var1(var1(:, 3) >= 0.09, :)` for greater equal than (your expected outcome). (I neglected the `1.0e+04 *`.)

Comment: I forgot the links, I wanted to provide. See [Indexing with Logical Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-3) and [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html) in the Matlab documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subsetting rows from Matlab for which specific column has value greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226622/subsetting-rows-from-matlab-for-which-specific-column-has-value-greater-than-zer)